# change rbenv download mirrors

Tags: ruby, rbenv

[Here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) says I can change mirror by setting `RUBY_BUILD_MIRROR_URL` environment variable:

> You can point ruby-build to another mirror by specifying the RUBY_BUILD_MIRROR_URL environment variable--useful if you'd like to run your own local mirror, for example. Package mirror URLs are constructed by joining this variable with the SHA2 checksum of the package file.

Then I set it. But it doesn't work:

```
aries@mac-book-air: echo $RUBY_BUILD_MIRROR_URL
https://ruby.taobao.org
aries@mac-book-air: rbenv install 2.3.0                                                                                                                                                                                        
Downloading ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
```

Besides, I didn't set `RUBY_BUILD_SKIP_MIRROR` variable in my env.

rbenv version: 1.0.0, ruby-build is the latest version. Mac OS X version:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.4
BuildVersion:   15E65
```

We can see that it does not use the mirror I set with that environment variable.

Anyone knows how to solve that? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `openssl` installed or one of the [other programs](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#checksum-verification) for calculating SHA2 hashes? If not, the mirror will be [automatically skipped](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#package-download-mirrors).

Comment: @BoraMa thanks for you help. according to   [this](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/823) I find that the mirror url does not support it. problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/823) I find that the mirror url does not support it. problem solved.